# Using common class in Python for multiple files

Tags: python, class, oop

I am creating numerous algorithms in different files using the same class attributes.

This class gets its attributes from clicks on a tkinter canvas.

```
class Algo: 
    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y 


def callback(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    return (Point(x, y))
```

Currently I have one algorithm using this class.
I plan on adding more algorithms in other files with the same Point attribute.

1. Is there a way to have make these attributes common between different class in different files?
2. Is it better to just create one class in a separate file and not use OOP for the other files, passing the attributes to functions?

Comment: Whether or not you share constructs between different modules, and use OOP, are two distinct concerns. I would define a class (or namedtuple or dataclass) for Point and import that in multiple modules… Mainly, if you have `Point = collections.namedtuple("Point", ["x", "y"])` (for example) in a file called `descartes.py` you can do `from descartes import Point` and you'll get the Point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to question 1 part a: "Is there a way to have make these attributes common between different class" That is just simple inheritance, illustrated below.

In so far as you are concerned about your classes being in different files:

1. Note, firstly, that in Python there is nothing to require 1 class per file.
2. See the comment by kojiro.
3. In general, the way you access stuff between files is by importing it.
4. If you want to inherit from a class defined elsewhere, import the class. If you want to use a function defined elsewhere, import the function. Importing should, however, have 0 bearing on the question of whether or not you use classes.

c

```
class Pointed:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
     
class Algo(Pointed):
    def __init__(self, x, y, something_else):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.something_else = something_else
     
algo = Algo(3, 4, "hello world")
print(algo.x)
print(algo.y)
print(algo.something_else)
```